# Submit button in form not working after choosing file with input written in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, filereader

I have html form for creating new product with image, so after choosing product image my html form submit button will become disabled. I've wrote file input action in javascript.

Here my html form code (piece of code):

```
<form>
<div class="form-group alert-up-pd">
  <div class="small-12 large-4 columns">
    <label for="">Добавить изображение</label>
    <div class="containers">
      <div class="imageWrapper">
        <img class="image" src=""></div>
      </div>
      <span class="file-upload">
        <input type="file" name="img" class="file-input">
        Выбрать
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

And here is javascript code:

```
$('.file-input').change(function(e){
  var curElement = $('.image');
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function (e) {
    curElement.attr('src', e.target.result);
  };

  reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});
```

If you need more info pls ask...

Comment: form submit works when I don't choose file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Code seems to work. Try to run that snippet:

```js
$(function(){
    $('.file-input').change(function(e){
    var curElement = $('.image');
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
      curElement.attr('src', e.target.result);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  });
});
```

```css
.image
{
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div class="form-group alert-up-pd">
    <div class="small-12 large-4 columns">
      <label for="">Добавить изображение</label>
      <div class="containers">
        <div class="imageWrapper">
          <img class="image" src="" />
        </div>
        <span class="file-upload">
          <input type="file" name="img" class="file-input" />
          Выбрать
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Can you provide an example where the submit button becomes disabled?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I've found my mistake, it was because of HTML Editor library (for textarea), so I shouldn't have put required attribute to textarea. I'm ashamed infront of you, sorry...